# how can i average value to each staff

Tags: calculated-columns

I have a table like this:

```
ID|Money|Staff1|Staff2|Staff3|Staff4
-------------------------------
1 |200  | John | Peter| Mary | John
2 |300  | John | Peter| Mary
```

and I need to calculate the average money of each staff in the same table.

```
ID|Staff1|Staff2|Staff3|Staff4
----------------------------------
1 |50    | 50   |  50  |  50
2 |100   | 100  | 100  | Null
```

Comment: Hi @raymond, what software/application are you using to store your table

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this could be using a subquery to give you the number of how many staff for that given ID. We calculate this by using `CASE` statements and the addition `+` symbol. Be careful not to quote your 0's and 1's or you will end up with a string instead of an integer.

In it's simplest format you can output the SQL using the following;

```sql
SELECT
a.ID,
a.Money/a.stcnt AS 'Each'
FROM
    (SELECT
    b.ID,
    b.Money,
    CASE WHEN Staff1 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Staff2 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Staff3 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Staff4 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS stcnt
    FROM staffmoney b) a
```

However if you require it with specific columns for each staff, despite the fact these figures will be identical, you can add another series of `CASE` statements to your top-level `SELECT` statement, which will look like this;

```sql
SELECT
a.ID,
CASE WHEN a.stcnt > 0 THEN a.Money/a.stcnt ELSE NULL END AS 'Staff1',
CASE WHEN a.stcnt > 1 THEN a.Money/a.stcnt ELSE NULL END AS 'Staff2',
CASE WHEN a.stcnt > 2 THEN a.Money/a.stcnt ELSE NULL END AS 'Staff3',
CASE WHEN a.stcnt > 3 THEN a.Money/a.stcnt ELSE NULL END AS 'Staff4'
FROM
    (SELECT
    b.ID,
    b.Money,
    CASE WHEN Staff1 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Staff2 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Staff3 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Staff4 > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    AS stcnt
    FROM staffmoney b) a
```

Not very efficient, my strongest advice would probably be to remodel your data so that you can calculate from rows rather than columns, but this will get you going with what you have if that is what you require.

Good luck!